# In iOS how to detect auto OTP using react native, its working on android but not working in iOS. I use npm i react-native-otp-verify

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, verify, one-time-password

I m trying to use auto fill confirmation code in iOS. its working fine on android but not on iOS. I use the same technique as documentation. on iOS i got not supported in iOS. Is iOS not supported auto fill confirmation code or there is another way in iOS? If there is then please share your answer or suggest another solution.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import {
  useLinkProps,
  useNavigation,
  CommonActions,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {
  CodeField,
  Cursor,
  useBlurOnFulfill,
  isLastFilledCell,
  MaskSymbol,
  useClearByFocusCell,
} from 'react-native-confirmation-code-field';
import OTPInputView from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {
  clearState,
  OTPCodeAction,
} from '../Redux/Features/PhoneNumberSignUp/EnterOTPSignUpKit';
import colors from '../Styles/colors';
import fontFamily from '../Styles/fontFamily';
import Button from '../Components/Button/Button';

import {createPost} from '../Redux/Features/PhoneNumberSignUp/PhoneNumberSignUp';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import Loader from '../Components/Loader/Loader';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

import {
  addListener,
  getHash,
  getOtp,
  removeListener,
  startOtpListener,
  useOtpVerify,
} from 'react-native-otp-verify';
const CELL_COUNT = 4;
const OTPEnter = ({route}) => {
  const [firstOTP, setFirstOTP] = useState('');
  const [otpCode, setOtpCode] = useState('');
  // const onChangeFirstOTP = val => {
  //   setFirstOTP(val);
  //   setValuesObj({...valuesObj, pin_code_sms: val});
  // };
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const ref = useBlurOnFulfill({value, cellCount: CELL_COUNT});
  const [props, getCellOnLayoutHandler] = useClearByFocusCell({
    value,
    setValue,
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const OTPCodeHere = useSelector(state => state.OTP);

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const handleNavigate = (routeName, clearStack, params) => {
    navigation.navigate(routeName, params);
    if (clearStack) {
      console.log('Clear');
    }
  };

  const post = useSelector(state => state.post);
  console.log('post', post);

  const [valuesObj, setValuesObj] = useState({
    device_type: route.params.deviceTypeParam,
    sms_number: route.params.contactNumberParam,
    device_identifier: route.params.deviceIdentifierParam,
    device_token: route.params.deviceTokenParam,
    pin_code_sms: '',
  });

  // console.log('gettingToken', route.params.deviceTokenParam);

  const {hash, otp, message, timeoutError, stopListener, startListener} =
    useOtpVerify({numberOfDigits: 4});

  useEffect(() => {
    getHash().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
    getOtp()
      .then(p => addListener(otpHandler))
      .catch(p => console.log(p));
    return () => removeListener();
  }, []);

  // console.log('hashGetting', getHash());

  const otpHandler = message => {
    try {
      const otp = message && (/(\d{4})/g.exec(message)[1] ?? '');
      // console.log('otp<<', otp);
      if (otpHandler !== null && otp) {
        setValue(otp);
        dispatch(OTPCodeAction({...valuesObj, pin_code_sms: otp.toString()}));
        handleNavigate('HomeScreen');
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (OTPCodeHere.success) {
      handleNavigate('HomeScreen');
      dispatch(clearState());
    }
    if (OTPCodeHere.message) {
      Toast.show({
        type: 'success',
        text2: `${OTPCodeHere.message}`,
        visibilityTime: 6000,
        position: 'top',
      });
    }
  }, [OTPCodeHere, value]);

  // console.log('value111', value);

  const onPressSendCode = () => {
    // validateField();
    dispatch(createPost(route.params.contactNumberParam.toString()));
    dispatch(clearState());
  };

  const onPressSubmitCode = async () => {
    dispatch(OTPCodeAction({...valuesObj, pin_code_sms: value}));
    dispatch(clearState());
    // console.log('valuesObj', valuesObj);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (post.success) {
      dispatch(clearState());
    }
    if (post.message) {
      Toast.show({
        text2: `${post.message}`,
        visibilityTime: 6000,
        position: 'top',
      });
    }
  }, [post]);

  const toastConfig = {
    success: internalState => (
      <View
        style={{
          height: hp('8'),
          width: wp('90'),
          marginHorizontal: wp('5'),
          backgroundColor: '#333333',
          borderRadius: wp('1.5'),
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: hp('1.5'),
            fontFamily: fontFamily.interLight,
            color: colors.white,
            paddingHorizontal: wp('3'),
            paddingVertical: hp('1.5'),
            lineHeight: hp('2.5'),
          }}>
          {internalState.text2}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ),
  };

  const renderCell = ({index, symbol, isFocused}) => {
    let textChild = null;

    if (symbol) {
      textChild = (
        <MaskSymbol
          maskSymbol="●"
          isLastFilledCell={isLastFilledCell({index, value})}>
          {symbol}
        </MaskSymbol>
      );
    } else if (isFocused) {
      textChild = <Cursor />;
    }

    return (
      <Text
        key={index}
        style={[styles.cell, isFocused && styles.focusCell]}
        onLayout={getCellOnLayoutHandler(index)}>
        {textChild}
      </Text>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={{uri: 'loginbglatest'}}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      resizeMode={'cover'}>
      <Toast config={toastConfig} ref={ref => Toast.setRef(ref)} />

      {post?.isLoading && <Loader></Loader>}
      {OTPCodeHere?.isLoading && <Loader></Loader>}
      <View style={{flex: 3.5}}></View>

      <View style={{marginBottom: hp('1.5'), marginHorizontal: wp('5')}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#1883b5',
            fontFamily: fontFamily.interLight,
            fontSize: hp('1.5'),
          }}>
          {`Enter the 4-digit OTP sent to ${route.params.contactNumberParam}`}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          height: hp('18'),
          flexDirection: 'column',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          marginHorizontal: wp('5'),
          borderRadius: wp('6'),
          paddingTop: hp('2'),
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: hp('7'),
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            paddingTop: hp('2'),
            paddingHorizontal: wp('5'),
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              marginHorizontal: wp('5'),
            }}>
            <View style={{}}>
              <CodeField
                ref={ref}
                {...props}
                // Use `caretHidden={false}` when users can't paste a text value, because context menu doesn't appear
                value={value}
                onChangeText={setValue}
                cellCount={CELL_COUNT}
                rootStyle={styles.codeFieldRoot}
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                textContentType="oneTimeCode"
                renderCell={renderCell}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            height: hp('8'),
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            marginHorizontal: wp('5'),
            marginTop: hp('-1'),
          }}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['#2A72B6', '#203B88']}
            start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
            end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
            style={{borderRadius: wp('3')}}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={onPressSubmitCode}
              style={{
                height: hp('5.5'),
                borderRadius: wp('1.5'),
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
               
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.btnText}>Submit Code</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </LinearGradient>
          {/* <Button
            onPress={onPressSubmitCode}
            height={hp('5.5')}
            text={'Submit Code'}
            colorsArray={['#2A72B6', '#203B88']}
            textColor={colors.white}
            textSize={hp('1.8')}
          /> */}
        </View>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          marginTop: hp('1.25'),
          marginLeft: wp('6'),
          marginRight: wp('3'),
          marginBottom: hp('3.5'),
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.lowerText}>
          Didn't receive the code?
          <Text
            onPress={onPressSendCode}
            style={{
              color: colors.white,
            }}>
            {' '}
            Tap here{' '}
          </Text>
          to resend. Having trouble with the authentication?{' '}
          <Text
            onPress={() => handleNavigate('SupportTicket')}
            style={{
              color: colors.white,
            }}>
            Raise a support request ticket
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
      {/* <View
        style={{
          marginHorizontal: wp('6'),
          marginBottom: hp('1'),
        }}>
        <Text
          onPress={() => handleNavigate('SupportTicket')}
          style={{
            fontSize: hp('1.5'),
            fontFamily: fontFamily.interLight,
            color: colors.white,
          }}>
          Raise a support request ticket
        </Text>
      </View> */}
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  root: {flex: 1, padding: 20},
  title: {textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 30},
  codeFieldRoot: {marginTop: 10},
  cell: {
    width: wp('17'),
    height: hp('7'),
    fontSize: hp('3.5'),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    color: colors.black,

    textAlign: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: wp('1.5'),
    borderBottomColor: '#DDD',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    paddingTop: hp('1'),
    marginBottom: hp('0.5'),
  },

  focusCell: {
    borderColor: colors.lightGrey,
    shadowColor: colors.lightGrey,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 8,
    },
    shadowOpacity: wp('0'),
    elevation: 1,
    shadowRadius: wp('10'),
  },
  lowerText: {
    color: '#1883b5',
    fontFamily: fontFamily.interLight,
    fontSize: '0.55rem',
    lineHeight: hp('2.5'),
    letterSpacing: -0.15,
    paddingRight: wp('2'),
  },
  btnText: {
    color: colors.white,
    fontFamily: fontFamily.interLight,
    fontSize: '0.65rem',
  },
});

export default OTPEnter;
```

Answer (score 2):

for iOS OTP reading you don't need any external library. React-native provides by default OTP read in textinput. You just need to add the below props in textinput.

```
 textContentType="oneTimeCode"
 autoComplete="sms-otp"
```

If you are using third party otp input component then also this will work.

But keep in mind in iOS OTP auto-read is different from what you get for android. Here you can see OTP on texinput, by taping on OTP on keyboard your textinput will be filled by OTP.
[image]

If only by doing not work then add below things in SMS at starting:

```
<#>code
```

for example your message should look something like below.

```
<#> code Your Google OTP to verify your phone number is 12345
'your android autoread key'
```

Comment: What's the android autoread key?